# Navigation errors between MainWindows and pages (WPF Application)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, variables, navigation

I am currently coding a wpf application that allows users to firstly select a process currently running on the local system, after clicking on a button, what the user has selected will be passed into a variable, and into the next few pages where they will need to answer and type in information into textboxes which needs to be kept into variables as well.

I need to store all of these information to be access in my final compiled page where i will display all of these information in a textbox. However i have ran into a few exceptions when trying to navigate through these pages/windows.

**Mainwindow.xaml.cs (Window)**

```
private void startTroubleshootButton_Clicknew(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            //get the selected process at column/index 0 and store it in a variable,
            var selectedProcess = listViewProcesses.SelectedItems[0] as myProcess;
            //var selectedProcess1 = listViewProcesses.SelectedItems[2] as myProcess;
            if (selectedProcess == null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no selection made");
                return;
            }

            //Store the associated process name and PID in proc1 and proc2 variable
            proc1 = selectedProcess.processName;
            proc2 = selectedProcess.processId;


            MessageBox.Show($"you have selected the {proc1} application {proc2} ");

            //instantiate the Pageone page

            Q1 pg1 = new Q1();
            this.Content = pg1;
        }
```

**(Q1.xaml.xs (Page))** Error receive after clicking **compileButtonClick**

```
private void compileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            string procName = window.proc1;
            int subprocPid = window.proc2;
            string procPID = subprocPid.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(procName + procPID);

            Compiledpage pg = new Compiledpage(); //this may not be required/efficient

            //Show Pageone in the current window
            this.Content = pg;

        }
```

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Page can have only Window or Frame as parent.'
```

**(Q1.xaml.xs (Page))** Error received after click **homeButtonClick**

```
    private void homeButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        this.Content = main;

    }
```

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Window must be the root of the tree. Cannot add Window as a child of Visual.'
```

**compiledpage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class Compiledpage : Page
    {
        public Compiledpage() 
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private string remoteIp;

        public void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {



            //instantiate the MainWindow and assign it to the 'window' variable

            var window = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
            string procName = window.proc1;
            int subprocPid = window.proc2;
            string procPID = subprocPid.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(procPID);

           ...
```

Is there a better way i can code for this "navigation and storing values across windows/pages" approach? I've heard that it is better to use UserControl but im not sure why thats the case.

Comment: "Page can have only Window or Frame as parent". You probably wanted to do `window.Content = pg`, not `this.Content = pg`

Comment: Your approach is generally wrong. You **cannot** create a new main window instance each time a button is pressed.

Comment: @dymanoid What if im trying to go back to my original main window from my Q1 page?

Comment: The main window stays the same all the time, you can go back to the original page using `window.Content = originalPage`.

Comment: The first window an app shows has a special significance and is the main window. You can instantiate some other window and set the mainwindow property of app to that. Hence an instance of say window1 could then become the main window.  By default when you create a new wpf app it gives you a window called mainwindow which is loaded first. So it's a bit confusing. But. You can create many instances of any window. Including one that happens to be called mainwindow.  By default, if you close the main window the whole app closes down.

Comment: It's difficult to give good advice without understanding more about aim. But.  Don't put windows inside windows. Only use pages for wizard style processes and host them in frames. Otherwise use usercontrols inside contentcontrols.